# How to efficiently query with a join and a where/order across two tables?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, join

I have two PostgreSQL tables:

- **`contents`**

  - `id` (primary key)
  - `captured_at` (date)
  - `status` (enum)
  - plenty of other columns we don't care about
- **`library_contents`**

  - `library_id`
  - `content_id`

With three indexes on `library_contents`:

- `content_id`
- `library_id`
- `content_id, library_id`

So each content can be in one or more libraries, and `library_contents` is the join table. Currently there are 40k `contents`, 100k `library_contents`, and the biggest library has 20k contents.

**My goal: I want to retrieve the contents in a given `library_id`, filtering on the status, and ordering on captured_at.**

Query is the following:

```sql
SELECT contents.id, contents.captured_at
FROM contents
JOIN library_contents
ON library_contents.content_id = contents.id
WHERE library_contents.library_id = 'somelibraryid' AND contents.status = 'PROCESSED'
ORDER BY contents.captured_at ASC
LIMIT 60 OFFSET 100
```

The result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE is the following:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=8469.34..8469.49 rows=60 width=45) (actual time=81.126..81.145 rows=60 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=8422.60..8473.77 rows=20466 width=45) (actual time=76.401..80.231 rows=18756 loops=1)
        Sort Key: contents.captured_at
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2239kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4042.90..6957.14 rows=20466 width=45) (actual time=28.720..67.323 rows=18826 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (contents.id = library_contents.content_id)
              ->  Seq Scan on contents  (cost=0.00..2802.74 rows=42474 width=45) (actual time=0.019..22.988 rows=41239 loops=1)
                    Filter: (status = 'PROCESSED'::content_status)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2487
              ->  Hash  (cost=3771.75..3771.75 rows=21692 width=37) (actual time=28.599..28.600 rows=19873 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1596kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on library_contents  (cost=0.00..3771.75 rows=21692 width=37) (actual time=0.010..22.003 rows=19873 loops=1)
                          Filter: (library_id = 'somelibraryid'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 76559
Planning Time: 0.677 ms
Execution Time: 81.631 ms
```

80ms is not the end of the world but I still find it's a bit too much given the amount of data, and also the number of contents is meant to grow, I expect libraries with more than 100k contents and I don't want the query to take one second .

As you can see in the query plan, it's performing **two sequential scans** of the tables and it's retrieving 20k library_contents (all the contents of the library) and 41k contents! To end with only 60 contents .

What I would like is to have an index on the filtered and sorted fields that could be used to retrieve directly the 60 final rows. But given the relational structure, an index on `[captured_at, status]` on `contents` would be useless as I'm first filtering on the library_id.

What are the options in such a case? I thought about:

- using VIEWS, to create a table that would contain "contents + library_contents" so it would look something like `library_id, id, captured_at, status, …all other columns of content`, but it means we duplicate a lot of information
- adding the filtered and sorted fields on `library_contents` which would have two new columns then `content_captured_at, content_status`. The duplication is lighter but we need to manage the synchronisation of the data (either by hand, either with a trigger maybe?)
- adding a column `library_ids` on `contents` which would be an array of string that would basically replace `library_contents`, and then we could add an index on `[library_ids, captured_at, status]` but I'm not sure it's a good practice nor if it would work properly

Are there other options? Another way to write the query maybe? It doesn't seem a super exotic use-case but I was unable to find answers and solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Try an index on `library_contents (library_id)`  or maybe `library_contents (library_id, content_id)`.

Comment: What indexes, apart from the PK you mentioned, exist?

Comment: Three indexes exist, on `library_contents`: `library_id`, `content_id`, `(library_id, content_id)`. I updated the question.

Comment: We're running into the exact same query optimization: in our case for a given "library" we may have 1M+ associated "contents", and a SORT is pretty expensive. Did you figure out the best way to do it? In my mind, a denormalized column on library_contents with triggers is the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd for captured_at to be in the contents table.  Surely when different libraries have the same book, they acquired it at different times?

> What I would like is to have an index on the filtered and sorted fields that could be used to retrieve directly the 60 final rows. But given the relational structure, an index on [captured_at, status] on contents would be useless as I'm first filtering on the library_id.

Did you try it?  You aren't doing the filtering, the database software is.  And it can apply the criteria in either order, depending on what it thinks will be faster. It would be better to have the column order in the index reversed, `(status, captured_at)`.  But if 'PROCESSED' is the predominate status, which seems intuitive, the order of the columns would not make a of difference.  You would need to pair this with an index on library_contents which includes content_id (possibly paired with library_id).